# Linq Cannot be Null error is thrown when query returns no records

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, null

I have the following query:

```
List<Models.PricingFormula> formulasInCat = new List<Models.PricingFormula>();
productsInCat = (from x in Model.PPPVMs 
    where x.CategoryId == category.ProductCategoryId select x).ToList();
```

The query is returning no records and the error I get is:

> Value cannot be null.

What's the proper way to handle this?

Comment: are you sure model and category are not null?

Comment: Thanks. Both Model and Categories are not null.

Comment: @JulianDormon On what part of the query does it throw that?

Comment: Did u initialize Model.PPPVMs?

Comment: It would help to see the stacktrace from your exception.

Comment: use `.FirstOrDefault();` and check `formulasInCat` null or not after it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Model` or `category` were null, there would be `NullReferenceException`. `Value cannot be null` is the message of `ArgumentNullException`, which means that most likely PPPVMs is null.

```
List<Models.PricingFormula> productsInCat;
if (Model.PPPVMs == null)
    productsInCat = new List<Models.PricingFormula>();
else
    productsInCat = (from x in Model.PPPVMs
        where x.CategoryId == category.ProductCategoryId select x).ToList();
```

Comment: What does PPVM stand for?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `DefaultIfEmpty()` before invoking the `ToList()` method.